# TextMate click to end of line

Tags: textmate

I use a variety of editors and for the life of me I can't remember if this is a default feature of TextMate or if it's a setting I've turned on somewhere along the line but each time I click on a line (in the empty space part after content) the cursor moves to the exact position I've clicked rather than jumping to the end of the line like every other editor seems to do. I've also noticed that Showing invisible characters (such as CR) displays nothing.

Can anyone tell me how to reset this behaviour? It seems to be the same for all types of syntax from plain text to markdown to languages. I just want to be able to see the invisibles and to click and have the cursor move to the end of that line and not to the actual position I've clicked with the mouse.

Answer (score 15):

Aha, got it! It seemed that I had turned on Freehand Editing Mode. Unchecking this option in Edit > Mode > Freehand Editing solved the problem and helped to convince me that I wasn't going mad. :S

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I must have accidentally hit the keyboard shortcut for Freehand mode and it was driving me a little crazy as well. In case anyone else was wondering what that shortcut is, it's <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>.